# deployment of custom addin into the microsoft office 365 store

Tags: office365, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-365, excel-web-addins

I have created a custom addin in react for some excel sheet operations so,
how can I deploy the custom addin in the Microsoft office 365 store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Make your solutions available in Microsoft AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center) article explains how to deploy Office add-ins to the `AppSource`. To include your solution in `Microsoft AppSource` and within Office, you submit it to `Partner Center`. You need to create an individual or company account and, if applicable, add payout information.

See [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) for all possible ways of deploying Office web add-ins.

Comment: did we also need an enterprise account or can be done by the normal account

Comment: Have you tried your a developer account?

Comment: See [Store step-by-step submission guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/add-in-submission-guide) for more information.